# Unequal number of grid items in row in grid container using css grid

Tags: css, css-grid

[image]

How can I make the following using css grid. I want all five box as children of parent container.

Comment: If you simply overflow bootstrap's grid system, I'm pretty sure they will give you this result. Like:
```<div class="container"><div class="row">
<div class="col-md-12"></div>
<div class="col-md-12"></div>
<div class="col-md-4"></div><div class="col-md-4"></div><div class="col-md-4"></div>
</div></div>```

Comment: Thank you but I was exploring css grid.

Comment: grid requires that you set how many rows or col element are supposed to be spanning across. No code, no help, only average guesses. clarify your question demonstrating your issue via the snippet button [<>] . else https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/ _ https://gridbyexample.com/

Comment: Thank you sir.  I will add snippet also. For this time it is already solved. But thank you for your feedback.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
.grid-container {
display: grid;
grid-template-columns: auto auto auto;
grid-gap: 10px;
background-color: #2196F3;
padding: 10px;
}

.grid-container > div {
background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
text-align: center;
padding: 20px 0;
font-size: 30px;
}

.item1 {
grid-column-start: 1;
grid-column-end: 4;
}
.item2{
grid-column-start: 1;
grid-column-end: 4;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>

<h1>Grid Lines</h1>

<div class="grid-container">
<div class="item1">1</div>
<div class="item2">2</div>
<div class="item3">3</div>  
<div class="item4">4</div>
<div class="item5">5</div>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

So something like this?

Comment: Yes. Same thing I have also figure out.

Answer (score 2):

Here is another idea with less of code:

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-auto-rows: 100px;
  grid-gap: 20px;
  width: 70%;
  margin: 50px auto;
}

.grid  > * {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 10px;
}

.full-width {
  grid-column: span 3
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="full-width"></div>
  <div class="full-width"></div>
  <div class="one-third-width"></div>
  <div class="one-third-width"></div>
  <div class="one-third-width"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

For reference:  [this css tricks blog](https://css-tricks.com/css-grid-one-layout-multiple-ways/).

grid-column property take start line and end line or start line and span value. So the idea is to make three column and give first two item full width.

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 100px 100px 100px;
  grid-row-gap: 20px;
  grid-column-gap: 20px;
  width: 70%;
  margin: 50px auto;
}

.full-width, .one-third-width {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 10px;
}

.full-width {
  grid-column: 1 / 4
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="full-width"></div>
  <div class="full-width"></div>
  <div class="one-third-width"></div>
  <div class="one-third-width"></div>
  <div class="one-third-width"></div>
</div>
```